# F# charts from csv

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I am pulling the following dataset (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/energy+efficiency)  using F# but can't figure how to match the data , I have an input and a output in X2 and Y1 (column names) but i keep having issue putting them together..

any help?

How would you do a basic chart from that csv using FSharp.Charting

Comment: You only supply a link, and don't explain what kind of data comes in. You don't explain much about the columns. You don't supply details about the problem. You don't show any code at all. If you can supply some more information, then the chances of getting help will be much better.

Comment: I just need a way to fetch the data from the csv file and parse it

Comment: A simple web search for `parse csv with f#` brought forth the following result (among others) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412423/library-for-reading-csv-file-in-f
Please do at least the basic reaserch in the future.